# How to attach to Payara from IntelliJ JProfiler Plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jprofiler

I want to use the show source (F4) context menu action in JProfiler. We have a very complex monolith multi module project and managing the class path in JProfiler is not an option. For this usecase one can also use the JProfiler IDE integration for Intellij with the JProfiler Intellij Plugin. If I start JProfiler in Intellij I cannot attach to my local Payara however. There are only two Intellij processes choosable. The Payara is running with the JProfiler agent and in standalone JProfiler I can attach to the Payara successfully. But in this case I cannot use the show source action. In the Intellij launch of JProfiler it seems not possible to recognize the running JProfiler agent. What am I doing wrong? Is this really not implemented?

See screenshot of available processes, but the standalone payara is missing, see process list on the right.

[image: missing process]

The suggested workaround via `Show Services` and running the installed `JProfiler Helper` service with local user doesn't work either, see the following error details from service:

```
Protokollname: System
Quelle:        Service Control Manager
Datum:         04.03.2021 15:29:43
Ereignis-ID:   7034
Aufgabenkategorie:Keine
Ebene:         Fehler
Schlüsselwörter:Klassisch
Benutzer:      Nicht zutreffend
Computer:      changed
Beschreibung:
Dienst "JProfiler Helper" wurde unerwartet beendet. Dies ist bereits 1 Mal passiert.
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7034</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-03-04T14:29:43.358009900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>8797</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="876" ThreadID="16752" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>changed</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">JProfiler Helper</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">1</Data>
    <Binary>4A00500072006F00660069006C00650072002000480065006C007000650072000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always choose the "Attach to JVM" action in IntelliJ IDEA (from the Run menu or from the tool bar). Then a list of running processes is shown and you can start a profiling session in JProfiler.

[image]

Comment: As I have written in the question this doens't work, because in the listed processes the payara is not present. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Is your answer true also if a JProfiler Agent is running in Payara or only if not?

Comment: No JProfiler agent must be loaded. All HotSpot JVMs will be detected if the run as the same user. Is your process maybe running as a different user?

Comment: No I start it with my user. Maybe it is special, that I run asadmin via cygwin, but at the end this shouldn't matter. Also using the button `Show services` doesn't work, but it also is not running as service anyway...

Comment: In the services control panel in Windows, locate the "JProfiler Helper" service, configure your user on the "Log on" tab and restart the service. Then "Show services" should show  your process. It does not matter if the process is actually a service.

Comment: Are you talking about services.msc? I don't have a JProfiler Helper service there. Is the installation not sane?

Comment: Yes, services.msc. The JProfiler helper will be installed the first time you use the feature from JProfiler and confirm the UAC dialog.

Comment: At the second attempt the service is installed now. I'm not sure I might have canceled the UAC dialog the first time, but I believe not. Service doesn't start with my user account. No real details in error message. See question update for details. Is there another log with more details what's wrong for the service now?

Comment: Also as system user the service is running anymore:
Der Dienst "JProfiler Helper" ist als interaktiver Dienst gekennzeichnet. Das System wurde jedoch so konfiguriert, dass interaktive Dienste nicht möglich sind. Der Dienst wird möglicherweise nicht richtig funktionieren.

Comment: This is coming from the checkbox to activate Desktop and service interactions. Also if I disable this checkbox and use a SYSTEM user again, the service is failing with an error nearly equal to the one posted in the question. Deleting the service and reinstalling solved to run it with SYSTEM user again. Cannot connect to my local Payara however...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what might be causing the crash when you change the user for the helper service. Can you try a different user account to check if it is that particular user only?